# undefined reference to "calcyear"

Tags: c, undefined-reference

I am new to programming if you could not tell by the advanced code I have laid out for you. I am reading a book on C programming and I copied this code out of it as an exercise and I have no idea why I am getting the error I am. PLEASE HELP!!!

I am getting an error that states `"file: main.c" "message: undefined reference to calcyear"`

```
/*bigyear.c*/

 #include <stdio.h>
 #define TARGET_AGE 88

int year1, year2;

int calcYear(int year1);

int main(void)
{
    printf("What year was the subject born?");
    printf("Enter as a four digit year (YYYY):");
    scanf("%d", &year1);

    /*calculate the future year and display it*/
    year2 = calcYear(year1);

    printf("someone born in %d will be %d in %d.", year1, TARGET_AGE, year2);

    return 0;

    int calcYear(int year1)
    {
        return(year1+TARGET_AGE);
    }


}
```

Comment: Move the final `}` to the line that immediately follows `return 0`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: ur copying skill is poor :)

Comment: My observation skills are apparently even lower...

Comment: @gdubs use your compiler in standard-compliant mode, then it will warn you about this

Comment: Don't tag a question C++ if it is about C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `int calcYear(int year1)` outside of the `main()` function.

You cannot define a function within another function in standard C.

Comment: A function doesn't need to be defined before being called, it just has to be declared before being called; which OP has done correctly. The problem is that the nested function is a definition of a different function to the one being called.

Comment: Yes I typo'ed `declared`, thx @Matt. "The nested function" : you agree that it is invalid, right?

Comment: The declaration (before `main`) is correct, the attempted definition is invalid